# Docker: env: can't execute 'python3': No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, environment-variables, dockerfile

I'm trying to run my docker container with environment variables but everytime it says: `env: can't execute 'python3': No such file or directory`. If I do the same thing without variables it's working fine.

Here's example of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM "This is coming from registry"

RUN apk add --update \
  python3

RUN mkdir -p /folder

COPY file.py __init__.py requirements.txt /folder/

RUN pip3 install -r /folder/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /folder

ENV ONE="test"
ENV TWO="test test"

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/env"]

CMD ["python3", "file.py"]
```

Should I change something in my Dockerfile or could it be possible that there's something wrong in my file.py? I'm using `os.environ` there. Thank you for your help!

Comment: the problem might be in your base image. I tried your Dockerfile with alpine as base image and it works fine.

Comment: Ok. Have to check if there's something what I should fix.

Comment: In my base image i have entrypoint.sh file where I have this:

#!/bin/ash

exec  robot "$@"

I think this is causing the problem maybe?

Comment: then it depends what that script does because you are not running it at all in the example you posted

Comment: When i'm running the file.py it will generate tests and run them using robot

Answer (score 0):

Why is your entrypoint as `/usr/bin/env` , it should be `python3`

If you want to use specific env then make it  `/usr/bin/env/bin/python3` ... or where ever is actual python3

Error is due to fact that python3 is not accessible and not with Environment variable

Comment: I tried this one but now it says "sh: python3: not found"

Comment: that means in your base image python3 is missing 
you need to give venv path which would be something like `/usr/bin/env/bin/python3`